Problem solving for Wilsonian Effective Action
I'm currently doing some basic questions on renormalisation group, but I've ran into a wall when it comes to one particular step in an answer. The question is as follows:

This problem is a toy model for the Wilsonian RG method (sometimes called the blocking method). Consider a theory of two variables $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. You can think of $x$ as the low-frequency (low-energy) variable and $y$ as the high-frequency (high-energy) variable. We want to integrate out the high energy variable to obtain an effective field theory of the low-energy variable. The UV action is
$$
S(x, y)=\frac{1}{2} S_x x^2+\frac{1}{2} S_y y^2+g(x+y)^4,
$$
where $S_x, S_y$ are positive constants. The path integral (which is an ordinary integral) is given by
$$
Z=\int d x d y e^{-S(x, y)} .
$$
(a) Determine the Wilsonian (blocked) effective action $\hat{S}(x)$ perturbatively in $g$ by integrating out $y$ :
$$
e^{-\hat{S}(x)}=\int d y e^{-S(x, y)} .
$$
Work up to order $g^2$.

I have gotten to the final step, but having checked the answer I'm not sure I understand what was done. The answer is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& e^{-\hat{S}(x)} =\sqrt{\frac{2 \pi}{S_y}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} S_x x^2}\left\{1-\frac{3 g}{S_y^2}+\frac{105 g^2}{2 S_y^4}\right. \\
& +\left(\frac{-6 g}{S_y}+\frac{420 g^2}{2S_y^3}\right) x^2 \\
& \left.+\left(-g+\frac{210 g^2}{2 S_y^2}\right) x^4+\frac{14 g^2}{S_y} x^6+\frac{g^2}{2} x^8\right\} \\
& \Rightarrow{\hat{S}(x)}=\frac{1}{2} \log( \frac{S_y}{2 \pi})+\frac{3 g}{S_ y^2} - \frac{48}{S_y^2} g^2 \\
& +\left(\frac{1}{2} S_x+\frac{6}{S_y} g-\frac{192}{S_y^3} g^2\right) x^2 \\
& +\left(g-\frac{84}{S_y^2} g^2\right) x^2-\frac{8}{S_y^2} g^2 x^6 \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$
I found the correct form of $e^{-\hat{S}(x)}$, but my issue is I don't know how to get to $\hat{S}(x)$. I assumed I would just take the natural log of both sides, but what get's me is that there is only one log on the RHS, which I could understand as $$- \text{ln}\Big(\sqrt{\frac{2 \pi}{S_y}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} S_x x^2}\Big) = \frac{1}{2}S_x x^2 + \frac{1}{2}\text{ln}\Big(\frac{S_y}{2\pi}\Big)$$ but I'm not sure about the rest and why there are no log terms? My initial thought was it would look something like this:
$$
\text{ln}\Big(e^{-\hat{S}(x)} \Big) = \text{ln}\Bigg(\sqrt{\frac{2 \pi}{S_y}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} S_x x^2}\{1-\frac{3 g}{S_y^2}+\frac{105 g^2}{2 S_y^4}. \\
+  (\frac{-6 g}{S_y}+\frac{420 g^2}{2S_y^3}) x^2 \\
+(-g+\frac{210 g^2}{2 S_y^2}) x^4+\frac{14 g^2}{S_y} x^6+\frac{g^2}{2} x^8\}\Bigg)\\
\Rightarrow -\hat{S}(x)= \text{ln}\Bigg( \sqrt{\frac{2 \pi}{S_y}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} S_x x^2}\bigg) + \text{ln}\Bigg(1-\frac{3 g}{S_y^2}+\frac{105 g^2}{2 S_y^4}. \\
+  (\frac{-6 g}{S_y}+\frac{420 g^2}{2S_y^3}) x^2 \\
+(-g+\frac{210 g^2}{2 S_y^2}) x^4+\frac{14 g^2}{S_y} x^6+\frac{g^2}{2} x^8 \Bigg)
$$
I'm sure I've went wrong somewhere silly but if anyone could help it would be appreciated.

I haven't checked the details of your integrals, but assuming that that's all done correctly, the only thing you're missing is log rules and a series expansion.  Using $a_i$ to mean the corresponding Wilsonian coefficient that you've derived,
\begin{align}
e^{-S(x)} &= \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{S_y}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} S_x x^2} \left(1 + a_0 + a_2 x^2 + a_4 x^4 + a_6 x^6 + a_8 x^8\right) \\
&= \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} S_x x^2 + \log\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{S_y}}+\log(1 + a_0+a_2 x^2 + a_4 x^4 + a_6 x^6 + a_8 x^8)\right).
\end{align}
Because all $a_i$ are order-$g$ or higher, writing $P(x) = \sum_n a_n x^n$, we have
$$\log(1 + P(x)) + O(g^3) = P(x) - \frac{1}{2}P(x)^2 + O(g^3).$$
If you throw this series expansion into the IR action, you'll find something that looks more familiar—there's a "mass renormalization" from $a_2$, and higher-order coefficients generate higher-order terms (or "higher-dimension operators" if you want to be fancy) in $x$.
Edit: May I ask where you got this exercise from?

That's perfect, thank you. And it's from a tutorial question that I had from my time at Durham Uni, it was a smaller class was on renormalisation group.
